# vaadin grid in polymer, Adding an expandable details row

Tags: polymer-1.0, vaadin-grid

There is a vaadin video explaining how to add expandable details to a vaadin grid.
I was looking for the same example, but using POLYMER.

```html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAyszSRzcDg&feature=youtu.be
```

Is there an example like this anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

That video is for the Polymer element,  1.x

If you need help with vaadin-grid 2.0, it works a bit differently.

Comment: Are these instructions for vaadin-grid 2.0?  https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-row-details.html   this is what i am trying to do in Polymer, but looking for the example code.

Comment: The vaadin.com docs site is still about 1.2. The upcoming 2.0 is still in alpha, soon beta. You can find examples for that in https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/2.0.0-alpha2/demo/index.html

Comment: Any update on 2.0 for vaadin grid. Even some example using polymer?  Also can I get URL to 2.0 just to confirm I'm looking at correct code base.  Thanks

Comment: Actually...   should I be using v1 or v2?

Comment: IrishGringo: v2 is highly recommended. You can find the source code here: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid/tree/2.0-dev

Comment: And as an update, we are roughly 1–2 weeks from beta for 2.0.

Comment: I'm going to spend this evening working with vaadin grid.   Do you have examples of how to do a click expanded display.  A way to create a template that opens with details of a site?

Comment: Just to confirm...   this is the Bower install command                               bower install --save https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-grid.git#2.0-dev

Comment: "bower install --save vaadin-grid#2.0-dev" is enough. There are some API changes since 2.0 alpha2, just a heads up, if tou’re looking at the examples for that (see the link in a previous comment). If you have more questions, https://gitter.im/vaadin/vaadin-core-elements is a good place to ask as well